# From Query Data into flexible CSV format

Tags: sql, csv

I wanted to compile below db table into a proper csv format by not knowing how many of the Node_ID will appear as this will impact the format of the csv header. Already done the sql query part, wanted to ask by any chance I can write a flexible code to form the csv file?

**Raw data :-**

```
_id     Node_ID Modality    Timestamp       Value
------- ------- ----------- ------------    ------
4930376 2002    Temperature 24/8/15 6:25    30
4930377 2403    Temperature 24/8/15 6:24    30
4930378 2004    Temperature 24/8/15 6:21    30
4930379 2203    Temperature 24/8/15 6:26    29
4930380 2211    Temperature 24/8/15 6:21    29
4930381 2401    Temperature 24/8/15 6:25    33
4930382 2411    Temperature 24/8/15 6:24    30
4930383 2101    Temperature 24/8/15 6:22    31
4930384 2201    Temperature 24/8/15 6:27    30
4930385 2111    Temperature 24/8/15 6:30    36
4930386 2113    Temperature 24/8/15 6:27    35
4934082 3200    Temperature 24/8/15 10:28   33
4934083 2402    Temperature 24/8/15 10:30   32
4934084 2213    Temperature 24/8/15 10:30   33
4934085 2103    Temperature 24/8/15 10:34   36
4934086 2423    Temperature 24/8/15 10:32   32
4934087 2421    Temperature 24/8/15 10:34   32
4934088 2413    Temperature 24/8/15 10:37   32
4934089 2102    Temperature 24/8/15 10:31   35
4934090 2202    Temperature 24/8/15 10:35   32
4934091 2404    Temperature 24/8/15 10:33   35
4934092 2121    Temperature 24/8/15 10:39   36
4934093 2002    Temperature 24/8/15 10:35   33
4940370 2123    Temperature 24/8/15 17:44   36
4940371 2422    Temperature 24/8/15 17:40   33
4940372 2001    Temperature 24/8/15 17:36   35
4940373 2301    Temperature 24/8/15 17:39   32
4940374 2402    Temperature 24/8/15 17:36   32
4940375 2103    Temperature 24/8/15 17:40   36
4940376 2423    Temperature 24/8/15 17:38   33
4940377 2421    Temperature 24/8/15 17:40   33
```

**Did this sql:-**

```
SELECT AVG(value), _id, Node_ID, Modality, value, Timestamp
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATE(Timestamp), HOUR(Timestamp), Node_ID;
```

From this previous post [SQL hour averaging in 24hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194998/sql-hour-averaging-in-24hours)

**What I wanted to achieve in a csv format:- (First row is header)**

```
Hour Node_ID1Value    Node_ID2Value ... etc(as not knowing how many will there be for the nodes)
6:00  30                    33                   ... etc
....
....
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you have?

Comment: Are you trying to pivot aggregate results? see this for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query